# .htaccess Deny from <IP> rule being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

```
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Apache 2.2.14
ISPConfig 3.0.4.2
```

A client of ours has an old web server that keeps crashing from what appears to be malicious bots/spiders that are probably spoofing their user agents.  I've tried just about every htaccess configuration that I can think of to try and stop these from crawling the site, but to no avail.

At this point, I'm trying to block individual IPs via .htaccess but nothing seems to work.

I have AllowOveride set to 'All' in the vhost config file:

```
<Directory /var/www/<this_website>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have the following mods enabled:

```
ls -x /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
actions.conf     actions.load        alias.conf            alias.load       auth_basic.load   auth_digest.load
authn_file.load  authz_default.load  authz_groupfile.load  authz_host.load  authz_user.load   autoindex.conf
autoindex.load   cgi.load            dav_fs.conf           dav_fs.load      dav.load          deflate.conf
deflate.load     dir.conf            dir.load              env.load         expires.load      fcgid.conf
fcgid.load       include.load        mime.conf             mime.load        negotiation.conf  negotiation.load
php5.conf        php5.load           reqtimeout.conf       reqtimeout.load  rewrite.load      ruby.load
setenvif.conf    setenvif.load       ssl.conf              ssl.load         status.conf       status.load
suexec.load      suphp.conf          suphp.load
```

And a snippit of the .htaccess file in the webroot:

```
...
order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from 180.76.6.45
...
```

I've verified that the .htaccess file is being read by adding a "Deny from All" at the bottom of the blocklist.  Upon hitting the home page with the browser, I get an Apache "Forbidden" page as would be expected.  However, while watching the access logs, I'm still seeing the following long after the .htaccess was written...

```
180.76.6.45 - - [15/Oct/2014:19:22:24 +0000] "GET /legacy HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
```

The same holds true for every other IP on the list.  Why are my "Deny from IP" directives being ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IP block is working ;-)

Apache access log reports page access successes and failures.  A failure is NOT an error.  An error is when Apache cannot successfully carry out a directive, load a module, or some such error.

The return code that follows the 'request path protocol' string `"GET /legacy HTTP/1.1"`, is `403` - which means 'forbidden', in other words, access was denied.  I don't know your log format so I cannot be certain, but the value after the '403' is probably the number of bytes returned, which is (as it should be) zero.